# Concatenate multiple directories name adding a counter in bash

Tags: bash, concatenation, rename, directory

I have to store the last 5 test results folders. Every time the tests are executed, a folder called "target" is created with all the results. The idea is to move that folder and add a counter (Ex.: target1, target2, ...). And store the last 5 executions.
It is important that when 5 folders exists and a new test execution creates a new folder, the oldest should be removed and all the folders renamed starting for the new one as target1 and the new last from target4 to target5

For now, I'm just storing the lastone.

```
rm -rf ${WORKSPACE}/target

if [ -d "${WORKSPACE}/tjba-hmi-toolkit/target" ]; then
  # Control will enter here if "target" exists.

    cp -r ${WORKSPACE}/tjba-hmi-toolkit/target ${WORKSPACE}/
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work with the minor glitch that first copy will have '0' suffix

```
$ cp -rp tmp cptest/tmp$(find cptest -type d -name 'tmp*' | wc -l)
$ ls -l cptest/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 4 luis users 273 abr 27 14:42 tmp0
drwxr-xr-x 4 luis users 273 abr 27 14:42 tmp1
drwxr-xr-x 4 luis users 273 abr 27 14:42 tmp2
drwxr-xr-x 4 luis users 273 abr 27 14:42 tmp3
drwxr-xr-x 4 luis users 273 abr 27 14:42 tmp4`
```